# What are rocker kneepads good for?

Tags: tools, protection

I recently bought a pair of knee pads that I thought would be useful for those tasks where I'm often on my knees. Imagine my surprise when I discovered that they don't offer a stable surface for kneeling on, but weeble wobble like crazy.

Turns out that these knee pads are designed like this, I guess they're called "rocker" knee pads - but I can't find any information about why you would want kneepads that aren't useful for kneeling on?

Comment: think about uneven gravel or rocky ground

Comment: @jsotola would that really be significantly better? Loose gravel will allow for enough shifting that flat pads would be fine. Doesn't seem like rocky ground would be any better... And when do you spend a significant amount of time on your knees in either of those materials doing construction work?